# Continuously decreasing accuracy of maxmind geolite city

Tags: geoip, maxmind, awstats

We've been using awstats together with Maxmind's GeoLite City (now GeoLite Legacy City) database for website statistics of a non-profit organization.

The percentage of unknown cities (the ones not found in the database) has long been at some 15 - 20%. But approximately since August - September 2013, the percentage jumped to over 40 - 50%, and these days (April 2014), it's at some 60%, which is really high, the data are becoming unusable.

We download the up-to-date GeoLite City database every month.

Does somebody know why has the Maxmind GeoLite Legacy City degraded that much in accuracy over past months? Is it because of new GeoLite2 City database format? We would consider moving to GeoLite2 City, but current awstats lacks plugin for that database.

Comment: I found the same, almost useless

Comment: Have you tried to examine the IPs that are coming in such as a monitoring tool with private IP or even the way you do translation, I can't believe that maxmind DB would fail to translate half of world's IPs as am using it for translation too.

Comment: Have you experienced this only for cities, or for countries as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to take a guess, I would imagine that as IPv4 is exhausted, we are starting to see more "weird" IP addresses that until recently have been marked as unused, and generally seeing IP allocations shaken up, so databases may just decide that they have no information about that IP range.